# How to plot Bode diagram with straight line approximation?

Tags: matlab

If I use the `bode (tf(num,den))` function to plot the Bode diagram I get a curved version. Is it possible to get a straight line version (as if you would calculate by hand)? Also, would it be possible to show the component lines that make the Bode diagram?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called Asymptotic Bode Diagram.

Matlab does not sketch the Bode plot, it evaluates the transfer function at various frequencies and draw modulus and phase on the two diagrams.

I found a script in [matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23870-asymptotic-bode-diagram), I didn't try it but maybe it is enough for you.

Greetings,

Nicola